belongs_to :through collection association that all belongs to same object
I have the following classes:
class Order
  has_many :line_items
end

class LineItem
  belongs_to :order
  has_many :line_item_production_items
  has_many :production_items, through: :line_item_production_items
end

class ProductionItem
  has_many :line_item_production_items
  has_many :line_items, through: :ine_item_production_items
  belongs_to :order
end

i want to create the association for ProductionItem:
belongs_to :order, through: :line_items
I know that all the line_items that are associated to a production item has the exact same order, so there will only be 1 distinct order. I found this post belongs_to through associations and tried using the following line in LineItem:
base.delegate :order, to: :production_items
but that threw an error (ArgumentError: The method .group() must contain arguments) because order is a reserved keyword. I cannot change the name order because it is part of the ecommerce plugin I use.
Is there any way to create this association within ActiveRecord, so i can do queries like ProductionItem.includes(order: [:bill_address, :ship_address]).where(WHERE_QUERY) without throwing an error?

If you want to include the Order directly from the ProductionItem you would need to denormalize and add the Order FK to the ProductionItem table.
Otherwise, you can do it with your current set up by eager loading through the associated LineItem like so:
ProductionItem.includes(line_items: {order: [:bill_address, :ship_address]}).where(WHERE_QUERY)

